# Flutter pod is not getting deleted

Tags: flutter

I had had installed firebase ad-mob to my project and after some days I removed it.

My pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.16.1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  json_serializable: ^3.2.5
```

here there is no dependence of firebase but in my Podfiles.lock it show me firebase and. when I run my iOS code from Xcode it says to me firebase framework not found.

I Don't know why am able to see the firebase installation description still In my Podfiles.lock.

Podfiles.lock

```
PODS:
  - Firebase/AdMob (6.14.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.50)
  - Firebase/Core (6.14.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.1.7)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.14.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.5.0)
  - firebase_admob (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/AdMob
    - Firebase/Core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core_web (0.1.0):
    - Flutter
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.1.7):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.5)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 4.2)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.1.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - FirebaseCore (6.5.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.4)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.1.2):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.2)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.1.0)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.8):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.4)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.56.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 6.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (6.1.7):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - GoogleDataTransport (3.2.0)
  - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (1.2.3):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 3.2)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.4.0)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.4.0)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - nanopb (0.3.9011):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.9011)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.9011)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - firebase_admob (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_admob/ios`)
  - firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
  - firebase_core_web (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core_web/ios`)
  - Flutter (from `Flutter`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
    - GoogleUtilities
    - nanopb

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  firebase_admob:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_admob/ios"
  firebase_core:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios"
  firebase_core_web:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core_web/ios"
  Flutter:
    :path: Flutter

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Firebase: 0219bb4782eb1406f1b9b0628a2e625484ce910d
  firebase_admob: d8c2bc95b5e0069406280ce6adb816cdee6aa595
  firebase_core: 920b9b2a74489a0cf6c5009b744f7f7f5fd84cf6
  firebase_core_web: d501d8b946b60c8af265428ce483b0fff5ad52d1
  FirebaseAnalytics: f68b9f3f1241385129ae0a83b63627fc420c05e5
  FirebaseCore: 632e05cc5e1199d9147122c16d92305eb04c34bd
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 511f4f3ed7d440bb69127e8b97c2bc8befae639e
  FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop: e9b1b023157e3a2fc6418b5cb601e79b9af7b3a0
  FirebaseInstanceID: ce993a3c3670a8f5d47ce371ac5d143c560608c5
  Flutter: 0e3d915762c693b495b44d77113d4970485de6ec
  Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK: 65e335fadc97c5a91a9d4546214bfd3a2fb11047
  GoogleAppMeasurement: db118eb61a97dd8c4f7014e368d3c335cbbcf80a
  GoogleDataTransport: 8e9b210c97d55fbff306cc5468ff91b9cb32dcf5
  GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport: 202d7cdf9c4a7d81a2bb7f7e7e1ba6faa421b1f2
  GoogleUtilities: 29bd0d8f850efbd28cff6d99e8b7da1f8d236bcf
  nanopb: 18003b5e52dab79db540fe93fe9579f399bd1ccd

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 083258d7f5e80b42ea9bfee905fe93049bc04c64

COCOAPODS: 1.8.3
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: hi did you find any solution for your question ? I have a case like yours

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the podfile.
First, go to ios directory `cd ios` (assuming that your working dir is your project).
Remove podfile and podfile.lock using `rm podfile` and `rm podfile.lock`
They will build again when you `flutter run` your project.